# Can't get AWS S3.getSignedURL work in Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to provide the user with a temporary url to download files in the AWS S3 service. To get this, the user asks my server, that authenticate the user, check permissions, and eventually asks S3 for a temporary (pre-signed) url, to send to the client's user.

But even if it's in the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property),
I get this error

```
 TypeError: s3.getSignedURL is not a function
```

This is my code

```
var AWS_S3_BUCKETNAME = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKETNAME;
var AWS_S3_REGION     = process.env.AWS_S3_REGION;
var AWS_S3_SECRET     = process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET;
var AWS_S3_KEY        = process.env.AWS_S3_KEY;

const AWS    = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId     : AWS_S3_KEY, 
                   secretAccessKey : AWS_S3_SECRET, 
                   region          : AWS_S3_REGION
                  });
const s3 = new AWS.S3();



var params = {
                Bucket : AWS_S3_BUCKETNAME,
                Key    : file_name,
                Expires: 60*5   //5 minutes
              };

 s3.getSignedURL('getObject', params, function(err, url)
                 {
                    if (err) { throw {msg:err, code:"AWS_ERROR"}; }
                    else { return url; }
                 });
```

this is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.208.0"
    }
```

Comment: I use the following import and it works for my setup `const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');`

Comment: and the following instantiation `const s3 = new S3({/*...*/});`

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: Think case in your method is the issue `getSignedUrl` vs `getSignedURL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are having wrong Signature in your s3 call,

```
getSignedUrl(operation, params, callback)
```

> It is Url not URL.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes! oh my God... sorry, stupid error. I wasted more than 1 hour to find what was wrong... checking among different versions...   thank you!

Comment: Had similar issues, usually, it gets resolved with Code Review. Glad it solved the problem. Copy and Paste also helps.